# Negative lookbehind with grep (on macOS)

Tags: macos, grep, negative-lookbehind

I am working with a directory of SQL scripts and trying to find any mention of `tables.table` that is not preceded either by JOIN or FROM (because I'm trying to identify which scripts may actually modify `tables.table` rather than reading from it). So I am trying to use a **negative lookbehind**, but I am wondering if this is simply not implemented on `macOS` `grep` because it's not working for me. Here's what I'm using:

```
grep -r "(?!JOIN )tables.table"
```

And MacOS is printing out:

```
-bash: !JOIN: event not found
```

I am running 10.13.16 macOS High Sierra in case it makes a difference. My questions are:

(1) Can I do a negative lookbehind with macOS, and if so how?
(2) How can I do a negative lookbehind that includes an "or" (because I want to find intances where neither JOIN nor FROM precedes `tables.table`.

****Edit****

I will attempt to provide a MCVE (which I thought I had above) by generating sample example files and explaining the problem in more detail. I have a massive and very deep set of directories containing SQL scripts (sometimes 4-5 directory levels down). I have no familiarity with these SQL scripts but I have been asked to try to identify which SQL scripts modify specific tables. Towards this end I want to find strings recursively in all these SQL files nested deep in a variety of directories and subdirectories which contain a mention of a specific table (let's call it table.tables) but only if that table's name is not preceded by the word JOIN or FROM since that indicates it's a data source and not being modified.

So let's say I have the following set of files (with their path names):

`/scripts/analysisA/prod/script.SQL` which contains the following text:

```
blah blah blah
FROM table.tables
```

`/scripts/analysisB/script2.SQL` which contains the following text:

```
blah blah blah
INNER JOIN table.tables
```

`/scripts/script3.SQL` which contains the following text:

```
UPDATE table.tables
blah blah blah
```

then I would like to have the result returned that `/scripts/script3.SQL` contains the line `UPDATE table.tables` and that be my only returned result for the above.

I am open to all suggestions for how to accomplish this. Thanks again.

Comment: You're asking an [XY Question](http://xyproblem.info/). "use a negative lookbehind" is just one possible solution to your problem, it's not the actual problem you started with, and then "how do I do negative lookbehind with grep on MacOS" is another problem but it's still not the problem you started with. Tell us what your actual, original problem is (the one you think you need a negative lookbehind to solve) with concise, testable sample input and expected output (i.e. a [mcve])  and we'll help you come up with a solution that works on MacOS.

Comment: The immediate cause of your error is your using double quotes instead of single quotes, which makes bash attempt history expansion on `!`.

Comment: `(?! ... )` is the syntax for negative look-ahead, not behind. But that doesn't matter anyway because it's the *Perl* syntax for look-ahead and `grep` doesn't support any form of look-ahead or -behind.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided a MCVE so I'm guessing but this script which just tests if JOIN or FROM appear anywhere on the same line as tables.table might be all you need:

```
awk '!/JOIN|FROM/ && /tables\.table/' file
```

or if you really do need to check for JOIN or FROM coming **before** tables.table:

```
awk 's=index($0,"tables.table") && substr($0,1,s-1)!~/JOIN|FROM/' file
```

Each of those scripts will behave consistently using any awk in any shell on every UNIX system. If neither does what you want then edit your question to include the missing MCVE.